# "Uninteresting mock function call" exception when mocking a function with a template base class

Tags: mocking, googletest, cpputest, utest

I have a base class A:

```
template <typename Type>
class A {
public:
    virtual const std::string& GetName() const = 0;
    virtual Type GetDefault() const = 0;
}
```

And a derived class B:

```
class B : public A<bool> {
public:
  const std::string& GetName() const override {return "bla"; }
  bool GetDefault() const override {return false;}
}
```

I want to Mock `class B` and its methods:

```
class MockB: public B {
public:
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetName, const string&());
  MOCK_CONST_METHOD0(GetDefault, bool());
};
```

Test:

```
MockB mock;
const std::string key = "something";
EXPECT_CALL(mock, GetName()).WillRepeatedly(ReturnRef(key));
SomeClass.method(mock); // this calls A<T>.GetName() and raises an exception
```

But I keep getting an exception:

```
unknown file: error: C++ exception with description "Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
Function call: GetName()
The mock function has no default action set, and its return type has no default value set." thrown in the test body.
```

It's used by the following method:

```
template<typename ValueType>
ValueType GetCustomSetting(const A<ValueType>& a) const
```

Which inside calls

```
a.GetName();
```

I've tried using `MOCK_CONST_METHOD0_T` but it didn't work as well.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with Google Mock 1.8. What is the signature of `SomeClass.method()`? Do you have non-const overloads of the mocked functions? Also, fully qualify `string` and `ReturnRef` to make sure you are using the right class/function.

Comment: I've updated the question to include the usage. I don't have non-const overloads. I've tried without `ReturnRef` and got a compilation error

Comment: I can only reproduce the exception if I **remove** the `EXPECT_CALL()` line. Maybe you forgot to rebuild all files?

Comment: It's on the same file ... I've also tried using `ON_CALL` and the result was the same

Comment: You must be missing some relevant information in your posted code. Try creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question.